# Excel: How To Write A Potential "IF" Formula With 3 Outcomes (For Work)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am looking to potentially create an "IF" formula (might be a different one) for my workplace. I'm not the best at excel, but not terrible either but am having trouble with this.

My workplace wants me to create a formula in which there will be 3 outcomes for our temperature testing. Currently I have the formula written like this for cell H46: **=IF((OR(D46>=C46, E46>=C46, F46>=C46)), "FAIL", "PASS")**

C46 is the max. allowable temperature, and D,E and F46 are the temperatures that were taken from the test. The formula basically says if D,E or F46 are greater or equal to C46, its a "FAIL" otherwise, "PASS".  The issue with my managers is that if C46 is blank, the formula counts "FAIL".

They want to have it where nothing changes above, EXCEPT the want to have it as well if C46 is blank with no values, that H46 will show "N/A". I don't know how to keep the current formula, but add in if C46 is blank that "N/A" or "n.a" will show instead of "FAIL".

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain functions in excel

`=IF(ISBLANK(C46),"N/A",IF(MAX(D46:F46)>C46,"Fail","Pass"))`

This will check for a blank C46 and return N/A else it'll check if the max value between D/E/F 46 is higher than C46 and return Pass or Fail

Comment: Perfect thanks so much it works perfectly! I did not know that ISBLANK was even a formula so that's extremely helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a perfect use of type conversion.

`IF(MAX(D46+0, E46+0, F46+0)>=C46,"PASS", "FAIL")`

Notice the use of +0.  This will force blank cells to be evaluated as a number preventing your error.